# What is the necessary and sufficient condition for a chain rule hold?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Assume that $f: [0,+\infty) \to [0,+\infty)$ is a $C^1$, increasing, and concave function with $f(0)=0$. Let $g:[0,+\infty) \to [0, +\infty)$ be a non-increasing function.

My question is that, does the following chain rule
$$\frac{d}{dx} (f \circ g)(x) = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) \quad a.e.$$
hold?

To my best, since $f$ is concave and $C^1$ on $[0, +\infty)$, the chain rule holds on $[c,+\infty)$ with any $c>0$, but how to handle the derivative near the origin? Is it still holds at the origin?

In some related works, like

- L. Ambrosio and G. Dal Maso, *A general chain rule for distributional derivatives*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc., vol. **108**, no. 3, pp. 691–702, 1990, doi:[10.2307/2047789](https://doi.org/10.2307/2047789)

or

- G. Leoni and M. Morini, *Necessary and sufficient conditions for the chain rule in $W^1,1_{\rm loc}(\Bbb R^N;\Bbb R^d)$ and $\rm BV_{\rm loc}(\Bbb R^N;\Bbb R^d)$*, J. Eur. Math. Soc., vol. **9**, no. 2, pp. 219–252, 2007, doi:[10.4171/JEMS/78](https://doi.org/10.4171/JEMS/78),

it is usually assumed that $f$ is Lipschitz. However, the Lipschitz assumption does not hold for some concave functions like $f(x)=x^\alpha$ for some $0<\alpha<1$.

Comment: Concave functions are Lipschitz except just the endpoints. Also, you have assumed that $f$ is $C^1$. So what is your question, really?

Comment: Well, $f$ is $C^1$ means that $f \in C^1((0, +\infty))$. @fedja

Comment: Yes, the chain rule holds for $[c, +\infty)$ for any $c>0$, but how to handle the derivative near the origin? Is it still holds for the origin? @fedja

Comment: "$x\in[c,+\infty)$ for any $c>$ ", is the same as "$x>0$" . So what is the question?

Comment: I found the result. Thie result is an easy consequence of Theorem 3.59 in the book ``A first course in Sobolev spaces: Second Edition", Print ISBN: 978-1-4704-2921-8.